# Using Python Script, to evaluate excel formula( NOT USING MACRO)

Tags: python, excel

I got a problem where we need to evaluate all the excel formulas from the python console. Currently, it's taking 12 hours to process 6500 policies which we want to optimize using python script. **Instead of using macro, we want to evaluate from python console to automate it**. We are trying to invoke dynamically all the excel formulas from the python console.
Here are the sample excel formulas being used:
Max, TRANSPOSE, OFFSET, AVERAGE, TRANSPOSE, IF, COUNT, ROUND, AND, SUM, ABS, IF .....
**Suggest how we could implement all the excel formulas using python, any alternative ** with TRANSPOSE, OFFSET, IF, DATE.

`

```
from xlcalculator import ModelCompiler

from xlcalculator import Evaluator

filename = r'Sample.xlsx'

compiler = ModelCompiler()

new_model = compiler.read_and_parse_archive(filename)

evaluator = Evaluator(new_model)

val1 = evaluator.evaluate('pol.tables!E2')

print(val1)

val2 = evaluator.evaluate('pol.tables!A2')

print(val2)

# #evaluator.set_cell_value('Sheet!A1', 200)
# # now Sheet!A1 value is 200
# # now Sheet!B1 value is 3
# # now Sheet!C1 value is (A1*B1)
#
# #val2 = evaluator.evaluate('Sheet!C1')
# #print("New valure for sheet!C1 is", val2)
```

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/phbXK.png]
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3rk6.png]

Comment: Just dropping my two cents here- have you considered using pure Python approach using Pandas? As in load the excel sheet(s) using Pandas, this step is fairly standard. And from there on you may carry on your calculations, this time in Python. Finally, output the pandas as Excel document.

Comment: yes, you get it right. The problem is that how could I implement all the excel formula here in python script. xcalculator doesn't have all the excel formulas.

Comment: Too bad, I don't know much Excel. But I'm sure you can do all the computations. Take a look at this documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html So for instance, TRANSPOSE could be done this way `df.transpose()`, SUM could be done `df.sum(axis=<axis>)`, etc. where `df` is your Pandas Dataframe. I think you can get more help from the community if you post some specific question where you're stuck.